# Вывод готового изображения php скриптом

Tags: php

В общем стоит такая задача:

Есть картинка

```
$path = 'folder/image/'; //путь к картинке
$image = 'hello.jpg'; //Имя картинки
```

и есть скрипт script.php
нужно сделать что бы при переходе по адресу http://site.ru/script.php?image=hello.jpg вывелась картинка, результат выполнения скрипта должен быть такой же как и при переходе по адресу http://site.ru/folder/image/hello.jpg

P.S такой бред не предлагать:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://site.ru/'.$path.'.$_GET['image']);
?>
```

В общем, задача: нужно скрыть реальный адрес картинки, но сделать возможность скачивать ее по с генерированном адресу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIN!

```
<?php
$file = 'folder/image/hello.jpg';
$image = file_get_contents($file);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

"Спасибо всем за помощь" :D

Comment: тогда уж так:

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    $file = 'folder/image/hello.jpg';
    readfile($file);

Comment: Почему не так?

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile('folder/image/hello.jpg');